# Path Not Found VB6

Tags: vb6, path, directory, backup

I'm trying to do backup on VB6.

This is my code:

> Private Sub Command1_Click() 
>  Me.CommonDialog1.Filter = "*.sql"
>   
>       Me.CommonDialog1.ShowSave 
>   If Me.CommonDialog1.FileName <> "" Then 
>  
>        FileCopy App.Path & "C:\Users\Bea\Desktop\symptoms.sql", Me.CommonDialog1.FileName & ".sql" 
>       MsgBox "Database had been successfully Saved on " & Me.CommonDialog1.FileName & ".sql"
>       End If End Sub

*And I get this error:*

**Path Not Found**

What's the possible problem?

Comment: store your directory and filename in a string, check wether they exist using dir(), and remove the app.path from your filecopy call

Answer (score 8):

Please learn to actually read the words in the error message. The problem is very clear.

The path at `App.Path & "C:\Users\bea\Desktop\symptoms.sql"` isn't there. If `App.Path` is `C:\VB6Apps`, and you concatenate (add) `"C:\Users\bea" to it, you end up with`"C:\VB6AppsC:\Users\bea", which obviously isn't a valid location.